# sqlite - ignore nulls in lag/lad

Tags: sql, sqlite

I use sqlite and have two tables. First contains a gapless series of dates (table datelist below) and a the second has dates and values (table: valuelist). Second table has gaps in the date series. As result i want to have a gapless timeseries with values. If for a given day there is no value in valuelist i assume the last value <> NULL before that day is the best approx.

With my SQL I could produce the table below. The SQL is on larger tables (10^4) and potentially larger gaps (~100) understandably not performant.

A coalesce of lag(value, 100), ..., lag(value, 1) is at least not elegant. (Dont know if it even works)

Question: Is there a more performant (and elegant) way to write this in SQLite? In other SQL-Slangs there ist an IGNORE NULLS in window functions. SQLites doesnt seem to have them. The FILTER part for Window Functions also dosent work - lag is not aggregate function. Can't use max() or so - the values are not ordered.

```
SELECT * FROM  
(
    SELECT d.dDate AS dDate, v.vDate
    , julianday(d.dDate) - julianday(v.vDate) AS diff
    , min(julianday(d.dDate) - julianday(v.vDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY d.dDate) AS min_diff
    , v.value
    FROM datelist AS d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN valuelist AS v 
    ON  d.dDate >= v.vDate
    AND julianday(d.dDate) - JULIANDAY(v.vDate) < 30    
    order by d.dDate DESC, v.vDate
) 
WHERE diff = min_diff
```

| dDate | vDate | diff | min_diff | value | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-10 | 2021-02-09 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 6 | gap - value from 09-02 |
| 2021-02-09 | 2021-02-09 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 6 |  |
| 2021-02-08 | 2021-02-08 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 7 |  |
| 2021-02-07 | 2021-02-04 | 3.0 | 3.0 | 3 | gap - value from 04-02 |
| 2021-02-06 | 2021-02-04 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 3 | gap - value from 04-02 |
| 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-04 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 3 | gap - value from 04-02 |
| 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-04 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 3 |  |
| 2021-02-03 | 2021-02-02 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 4 | gap - value from 02-02 |
| 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-02 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 4 |  |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-01 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 3 |  |

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS datelist;
CREATE TABLE datelist (dDate text);
INSERT INTO datelist values('2021-02-01');
INSERT INTO datelist values('2021-02-02');
INSERT INTO datelist values('2021-02-03');
INSERT INTO datelist values('2021-02-04');
INSERT INTO datelist values('2021-02-05');
INSERT INTO datelist values('2021-02-06');
INSERT INTO datelist values('2021-02-07');
INSERT INTO datelist values('2021-02-08');
INSERT INTO datelist values('2021-02-09');
INSERT INTO datelist values('2021-02-10');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS valuelist;
CREATE TABLE valuelist(vDate text, value int );
INSERT INTO valuelist values('2021-02-01', 3);
INSERT INTO valuelist values('2021-02-02', 4);
INSERT INTO valuelist values('2021-02-04', 3);
INSERT INTO valuelist values('2021-02-08', 7);
INSERT INTO valuelist values('2021-02-09', 6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is to use `lead()` to get ranges for the values table.  Then join the results together:

```
select d.*, v.value
from datelist d left join
     (select v.*, lead(vdate) over (order by vdate) as next_vdate
      from valuelist v
     ) v
     on d.dDate >= v.vDate and
        (d.dDate < v.next_vdate or v.next_vdate is null);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1c0e92fce28ae519fa037857a98d73ac) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Rewrote it to my originating problem and it does exactly what i wanted :-) Thank you! 
Fun Fact: I used the same idea before to find out the length of the gaps. I tought to complicated... At the end so easy :-)
-- determine the length of gaps in the sequence: 
SELECT lag(vdate) OVER (ORDER BY vdate) , vdate , julianday(vdate) - julianday(lag(vdate) 
OVER (ORDER BY vdate)) AS gap_length 
FROM valuelist ORDER BY gap_length